# Apache FOP Xml to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to transform XML financial data to PDF in Java using xslt and Apache FOP. But I'm getting following exception while transforming XML to PDF with created xsl-fo.

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 3; The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd is included in my xslt file. It has really that line without closing tag. I read on https://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/23058335/ that its SGML DTD. I can't transform this xslt to xsl-fo using Apache FOP, because underlying saxon can't parse sgml dtd?

Code for transform xslt to xsl-fo and then xsl-fo to PDF look like following. Could someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong? And how can I transform XML to PDF? Thanks in Advance.

```
 private byte[] generateFOFromXML(Source xslt, Source invoice) throws TransformerException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            //Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

            //Setup input for XSLT transformation

            //Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
            Result res = new StreamResult(out);

            //Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            transformer.transform(invoice, res);
            return out.toByteArray();
        } finally {
//            try {
//                out.close();
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }

    }

     byte[] xslFO = generaterFOFromXML(xsltSource, invoiceSource);

                FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI());
                builder.setStrictFOValidation(false);
                FopFactory  fopFactory=  builder.build();

//                FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
                FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

                ByteArrayOutputStream tempBAO = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, tempBAO);
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
                Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                Source foSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xslFO));

                transformer.transform(foSource, result);
```

Comment: You can't parse SGML (HTML 4.01 is an SGML DTD) with an XML parser... With such an input, you can't apply an XSL transformation like you want to in your Java code.

Comment: @potame thanks for your answer. i was able to transform xml to html using xlst. what is your suggestion for transforming xml and xslt to pdf ?

Comment: You have to transform xml to xsl-fo with xslt, then fop will make a pdf out of that.

Comment: yes i did. first i transformed from xml using xslt to fo. And then to pdf from fo.  But it didnt work. I'm still getting 'SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 3; The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.'

Comment: Please share the xsl that you use to create fo-xml